# All vue props and data give the error 'Property ' ' does not exist on type ' with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I recently added typescript to my vue project and every time I access a value in props or data I get this error

```
37:46 Property 'activity' does not exist on type '{ props: { activity: { type: ObjectConstructor; required: boolean; }; }; methods: { formatDistance: (distance: number, setting_unit: string) => string; }; mounted: () => void; }'.
    35 |         },
    36 |         mounted: function () {
  > 37 |             var activitymap = L.map('map' + this.activity['activity']['id']).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
       |                                              ^
```

This is my props

```
    props: {
        activity: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
```

and this is the method it is being used in

```
    mounted: function () {
        var activitymap = L.map('map' + this.activity['activity']['id']).setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: process.env.VUE_APP_MAPBOX_KEY
        }).addTo(activitymap)

        var gpxGroup = new L.FeatureGroup();

        activitymap.addLayer(gpxGroup);

        omnivore.gpx(this.activity['activity']['activity_log_url']).addTo(gpxGroup).on('ready',
            function () {
                activitymap.fitBounds(gpxGroup.getBounds());
            }
        )
    }
```

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's hard to use typescript with VueJS without vue-class-component. Do you use `Vue.extend()` to define your component?

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        activity: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: No, on the level above props I just have `export default` which is inside `<script lang='ts'>`

Comment: In this case, typescript won't find your property as it is an object for the compiler. You should use `export default export default Vue.extend({ .... });`

Comment: This fixed it but there is a typo in your example, default is missing the l

Answer (score 12):

In Vue 3 I solved this problem by wrapping the exported component dictionary in `defineComponent`.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.defineComponent({
    data() { ... },
    methods: { ... },
    ...
});
```

Comment: This solved my issues too. I'm not sure why Typescript messed so much with types if I didn't use defineComponent() and everything was fine using it.

Comment: @Josh Could you add example code so others have easier time to understand how to exactly wrap it and where? I have a `DefineComponent` in a separate `.ts` file, but I want to use the component code like in Vue 2 inside a `.vue` file...

Comment: Okay got it here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components

Comment: Yeah, that's it exactly

Comment: `import { defineComponent } from 'vue';` then Use `defineComponent` ___instead of___ `Vue.defineComponent` [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#defining-vue-components) or use `class based component`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in Vue 3 just by uninstalling Vetur and installing Volar.